# Function to flip image - works on iOS 5.0, but gives bad access on iOS 6.0

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, xcode4

```
-(UIImage * ) flipImage: (UIImage * ) imag {
    CGImageRef img1 = imag.CGImage;
    CFDataRef dataref = CopyImagePixels(img1);
    UInt8 * data = (UInt8 * ) CFDataGetBytePtr(dataref);
    int length = CFDataGetLength(dataref);
    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(img1);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(img1);
    size_t bytesPerRow = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(img1);
    size_t bitsPerComponent = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(img1);
    size_t bitsPerPixel = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(img1);
    NSLog(@"size %d x %d pixel:%d   component :%d length:%d", (int) width * 4, (int) height, (int) bitsPerPixel, (int) bitsPerComponent, length);
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < height / 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (width * 4); j++) {
            temp = (int) data[i * width * 4 + j];
            NSLog(@"first data :%ld  second data:%ld", i * width * 4 + j, width * 4 * (height - 1 - i) + j);
            data[i * width * 4 + j] = data[(width * 4 * (height - 1 - i)) + j];
            data[(width * 4 * (height - 1 - i)) + j] = (size_t) temp;
        }
    }
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGImageGetColorSpace(img1);
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(img1);
    CFDataRef newData = CFDataCreate(NULL, data, length);
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(newData);
    CGImageRef newImg = CGImageCreate(width, height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorspace, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    //[imvcomment setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImg]];
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage: newImg];
    CGImageRelease(newImg);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
}

CFDataRef CopyImagePixels(CGImageRef inImage) {
    return CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(inImage));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug using breakpoints? You can identify in which line the crash is happening?

Comment: @Krishnabhadra yeah it will crash in for loop .

Comment: @Krishnabhadra yeah it will crash in for loop .first time image flip but in second time it will BAD ACCESS..

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't you replace all of this nasty looking code with a single call to `imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:` as described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageWithCGImage%3ascale%3aorientation%3a)?

```
UIImage *flipped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imag.CGImage scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationDown];
```

You may need to change the orientation value to a different one depending on what you are after- "flip" is a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the bytes per row, but you're not using it. Images may have additional padding at the end of each row. (This is typical in images that have an odd width.) You could write it something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < height / 2; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        temp = (int)data [ i * bytesPerRow + j ];
        data[i * bytesPerRow + j] = data[(bytesPerRow * (height - 1 - i)) + j];
        data[(bytesPerRow * (height - 1 - i)) + j] = (size_t) temp;
    }
}
```

Also, you might want to verify that `bitsPerPixel` fits within an int. If you have 4 floating point channels in the image, it might not.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any problem with your code, i implemented your code and got the flip image.

here is my code.

```
UIImage *imgg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"route.png"];

UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
image.frame=CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 50);
[self.view addSubview:image];

image.image  =  [self flipImage:imgg];
```

Comment: >i have solve this problem. in iOS 6 CFDataRef not support so instead of CFDataRef 'dataref=CopyImagePixels(img1);' i use 'CFMutableDataRef dataref=CFDataCreateMutableCopy(0,0,CopyImagePixels(img1));' and now it work on both iOS 5 & iOS 6 also...thanks all for try to solve my issue...

Comment: Your wc @bunti.iosdeveloper..